# Does Express require me to DELETE using a POST route?

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, express, pug

The following code successfully deletes a record when a button is clicked and confirmed:

**Router (Express):**

```
router.post('/meetings/delete/:slug', catchErrors(meetingController.deleteMeeting));
```

**Controller:**

```
exports.deleteMeeting = async (req, res) => {
  const slug = req.params.slug;
  const meeting = await Meeting.remove({ slug });
  req.flash('success', 'meeting successfully deleted!');
  res.redirect(`/meetings`);
};
```

**View Template (Pug/Jade):**

```
form.delete-meeting-form(method='POST' action=`/meetings/delete/${meeting.slug}?_method=DELETE`)
    input.button.button--delete(type='submit' value='DELETE MEETING' onclick='return confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this meeting? (Cannot be undone)")')
```

This code works great as-is. However, it seems strange to me that I seem to be required to use a POST route in order to complete my DELETE request. When I attempted to use `router.delete` to form the route, it did not work.

I understand that HTML doesn't support DELETE and PUT/PATCH requests very well, but why was it a problem to name my Express route `delete`? Did I do something wrong?

Comment: express supports delete method based routes https://expressjs.com/en/starter/basic-routing.html

Comment: Thank you, Arpit. I saw that, but when I tried to implement it, I no longer hit the controller. Only when I switched to POST did it finally work.

Comment: with forms and simple submit buttons there is not way you can use delete routes although if you try ahax it will work. What does it show when you hit the route ? 404?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Delete will work fine with express.](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.delete.method) Regular HTML forms do not support delete. If you add a delete route to your application you can test the delete method with ajax (fetch, axios, jQuery, etc.) or curl:

```
curl -X "DELETE" http://foo/meetings/some-meeting
```

If you'd like to be able to use regular HTML forms with `delete`, check out the [method-override middleware](https://github.com/expressjs/method-override). The [custom logic](https://github.com/expressjs/method-override#custom-logic) section shows how you'd create an override that's similar to how Rails handles method overrides.

Comment: That's very interesting. When I hit the route with curl, as you suggest, the controller executes successfully. But if I attempt it using the HTML form/button, it is unsuccessful. So the issue must be the HTML?

Comment: Correct, HTML forms do not support delete. You can use ajax to make a delete request.

Comment: Yuck, that's annoying. I know in Rails templates it automatically converts into something HTML can work with. And I thought that my code above (specifically method='POST' action=`/meetings/delete/${meeting.slug}?_method=DELETE`) would have the effect of bypassing HTML's limitations. Apparently not?

Comment: _method=DELETE is not a standard. Rails treats POSTs that have _method=DELETE in the body as actual DELETE requests.

Comment: Ah, I see. It's just a Rails thing, then. :(

Comment: @MicahBales take a look at [`method-override`](https://github.com/expressjs/method-override), which implements something similar to Rails (example [here](https://github.com/expressjs/method-override#override-using-a-query-value)).

Comment: Thanks, @robertklep. I'll take a look.

Answer (score 0):

This is a matter of convention. jQuery (and Javascript in general) supports `DEL` and `PUT` in addition to `GET` and `POST`, but nothing is stopping you from deleting using `GET` or `POST`, as you are doing it above. It is a good practice to synchronize your api calls with corresponding calls but it takes a bit more effort to setup.